# Table cell height is more in IE than chrome/firefox

Tags: html, css

In my web page I have a table structure. In Firefox and chrome it is showing correct height but in IE it is showing more height than the content in it. In my page on left side there is menu and each menu in one `<td>`. I want height of that menu i.e. `<td>` to remain constant in IE. In chrome and Firefox, height of `<td>` remains constant but in IE height becomes more than content it.

**css :**

```
td{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;

}
Doctype--<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

**screen shot**

In chrome-
[image]

And in IE-
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: is the table used for left section only?If yes try using float:left; for each left element

Comment: No, whole structure is in table. whole right side part is just one td of that table.

Comment: Try Set float:left; property for all elements listed in the left -side td

Comment: Try using float(with width) or display attr style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put your menu in a container div and give the td (containing this div) a vertical align that suits you:

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle">
<div>
     your menu here
</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial for most IE to have white spaces removed white space between `<TD>` tags

Example:

```
<td>Some stuff</td>
  <td>Some stuff</td>
```

Will look different than

```
<td>Some stuff</td><td>Some stuff</td>
```

Clean up your white-spaces and I highly recommend Eric Meyer's CSS reset for cross-browser compatibility:    http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you, use normalizer.css, it makes you forms and tables, etc... same in all browsers.

Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with
   modern    standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.

```
http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/
```